# Change terminal size when executing ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal

Is there a way to change the size of the terminal window when executing a program from the command line? I tried using IO#winsize= but it does not seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Doing so would be totally disrespecting user settings. I'd be very annoyed if some program decided that it knows better what size of __my__ terminal should be.

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev While I share your feelings in the general case, there are examples where it would be OK. Perhaps the application is changing terminal settings at the request of the user. For example, user hits a key to toggle the application's terminal between regular and a "large" (eg half-screen) sizes. Perhaps the application is an unusually interactive one, eg. a game, in which moving and resizing one (or more!) terminals is part of the gameplay.

Comment: (cont) ...I just remembered: Vim itself falls into this category: If you :set lines=X, then it resizes the terminal, at the user request.

Answer (score 1):

There are [Xterm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) for window manipulation:

```
CSI Ps ; Ps ; Ps t
          Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions).
          These controls may be disabled using the allowWindowOps
          resource.  Valid values for the first (and any additional
          parameters) are:
            Ps = 1  -> De-iconify window.
            Ps = 2  -> Iconify window.
            Ps = 3  ; x ; y -> Move window to [x, y].
            Ps = 4  ; height ; width -> Resize the xterm window to
          height and width in pixels.
            Ps = 5  -> Raise the xterm window to the front of the stack-
          ing order.
            Ps = 6  -> Lower the xterm window to the bottom of the
          stacking order.
            Ps = 7  -> Refresh the xterm window.
            Ps = 8  ; height ; width -> Resize the text area to
          [height;width] in characters.
            Ps = 9  ; 0  -> Restore maximized window.
            Ps = 9  ; 1  -> Maximize window (i.e., resize to screen
          size).
            Ps = 1 1  -> Report xterm window state.  If the xterm window
          is open (non-iconified), it returns CSI 1 t .  If the xterm
          window is iconified, it returns CSI 2 t .
            Ps = 1 3  -> Report xterm window position as CSI 3 ; x; yt
            Ps = 1 4  -> Report xterm window in pixels as CSI  4  ;
          height ;  width t
            Ps = 1 8  -> Report the size of the text area in characters
          as CSI  8  ;  height ;  width t
            Ps = 1 9  -> Report the size of the screen in characters as
          CSI  9  ;  height ;  width t
            Ps = 2 0  -> Report xterm window's icon label as OSC  L
          label ST
            Ps = 2 1  -> Report xterm window's title as OSC  l  title ST
            Ps >= 2 4  -> Resize to Ps lines (DECSLPP)
```

To invoke them from Ruby you could use: (`"\e["` is the code for CSI)

```
print "\e[8;40;80t" # resizes terminal window to 40x80 characters
```

This only works if your terminal supports the control sequence.

Comment: I tried using these exit commands and they did not seem to work. I have used escape codes before to change the foreground and background colors, but they don't seem to be working for resizing. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: OSX Terminal.app supports the window-size control sequence (checked by running `resize -s 40 80`, which sends that particular string). [resize](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) is a utility program, of course (not Ruby).